# The moments of the sum of variables following standard normal distribution divided by the sum of the squares of them

Tags: expectation, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions, ratio, chi-squared

Let i.i.d. $t_i\sim N(0,1), i = 1,2,\dots,n$, and

\begin{equation}
X = \frac{\sum_i t_i}{\sum_i t_i^2}.
\end{equation}

How to calculate the first two moments of $X$, i.e., $\mathrm{E}(X)$ and $\mathrm{E}(X^2)$?

I did some simulation studies and am almost sure that $\mathrm{E}(X) = 0$ and $\mathrm{E}(X^2) = \frac{1}{n-2}$. However, I failed to get the derivation in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? You will find you'll get a better reception if you show your work in progress, no matter how small. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. Some progress added.

Comment: Well, $E(X)=0$ is trivial because each $t_i$ has a distribution symmetric about $0$. (You have to verify the tails don't make for an $\infty-\infty$ situation, but that's easy in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you forgot to state that the $t_i$ are independent.

The expectation of any function that's antisymmetric in one of the $t_i$ is zero. Thus, $E(X)=0$ without further calculation.

For $E\left(X^2\right)$, the mixed pairs in the sum have zero expectation because they're odd in both factors, so what remains is

$$
E\left(X^2\right)=\frac{\sum_it_i^2}{\left(\sum_it_i^2\right)^2}=\frac1{\sum_it_i^2}=r^{-2}\;,
$$

where $r$ is the radial coordinate in $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates for the $t_i$. The density for $r$ is proportional to $r^{n-1}\mathrm e^{-\frac12r^2}$, so the expectation of $r^{-2}$ is

$$
E\left(X^2\right)=\frac{\int_0^\infty r^{n-3}\mathrm e^{-\frac12r^2}\mathrm dr}{\int_0^\infty r^{n-1}\mathrm e^{-\frac12r^2}\mathrm dr}=\frac{2^{\frac n2-2}\Gamma\left(\frac n2-1\right)}{2^{\frac n2-1}\Gamma\left(\frac n2\right)}=\frac1{n-2}\;.
$$

Comment: Yes I forgot. $t_i$ are independent. And thank you very much.